# How would I increase the size of my root partition in this case?

Tags: partitioning, root

I'm using a machine that's partitioned with Windows. How would I go about moving the 10GB unallocated space that I've just taken from W10 and transfer it into my root partition so that I can upgrade my distro to 20.4?

Partition table from GParted
[image: Partition table from GParted]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- add it to the front of sda5, finish this task.
- take it away at the end of sda5, finish this task.
- add it to the front of sda6, finish this task.

Since sda5 is largely full it will probably take some time to finish.

A few comments:

- There is an easier method: remove the swap partition, add it to sda6 and start using a swapfile. That way doing this becomes a lot easier: next time you can take it from the front of sda8 (sda7 after removing swap) and add it to sda6 in 1 task in gparted.
- Mind that you also should examine your /. A desktop with 15Gb in root tends to have files there that do not belong in it. Like a database or website. Our base install is not 15Gb (not even close to it) and even installing every piece of software from the software center is going to be less than 15Gb.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly. Where should I look within /?

Comment: I actually had a look; most of it seems to be in /usr/share. Any idea where I should look within there?